# Split Image into Two parts and show the images PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want an image to split into two parts and save the images and return the image url. i've written code but unfortunately its not working, if you know the solution please let me know

```
$orig = site_url('/') . $_POST['BatImageUrl'];

$width = 2500;
$height = 300;

if( $_POST['partName'] == 'handle' ) {

    $leftSide = imagecreatetruecolor($width/2, $height);

    $handleimage = imagecreatefrompng("handle-image.png"); 

    imagecopy($leftSide, $orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width/2, $height);

    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    imagepng($leftSide, $handleimage);

    imagedestroy($leftSide);

} else {

    $rightSide = imagecreatetruecolor($width/2, $height);

    $barrelimage = imagecreatefrompng("barrel-image.png"); 

    imagecopy($rightSide, $orig, 0, 0, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height);

    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    imagepng($rightSide, $barrelimage);

    imagedestroy($rightSide);

}

imagedestroy($orig);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178906/3599237

Comment: @Akam I've seen that link, please point the error in my code, why can't i get the results?

Comment: "not working" is no Description of the Error. If you look for Help make it as easy as possible to help you.